# Centering longtable in narrow single column document

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am having trouble centering my `longtable`. My `\textwidth` is set to a narrow width purposefully - it gives me the line breaks close to the scan of the article that I am transcribing - so makes the transcription easier. Not certain if that might be affecting the centering of my table. I have only included the first row of my table for demonstration purposes.

I have tried `\setlength\LTleft{\fill}` and `\setlength\LTright{\fill}` and placing the entire table in a `changepage` environment - all to no avail.

Thanks in advance for assistance.

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[textwidth=9.5cm, textheight=20cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

Nous n’insisterons pas davantage sur ce sujet et nous
allons passer maintenant aux applications (1).

\vspace{1em}
\centerline{X. — \textsc{Applications}.}

\vspace{1em}
\centerline{\textit{Transformations des propriétés segmentair es.}}

\vspace{1em}
\begin{longtable}[c]{p{.65\textwidth}|p{.65\textwidth}}
69. Prenons d’abord ce théorème:

\vspace{1em}
Deux droites parallèles sont
coupées par trois droites $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$,
l’une aux points $A,B,C$,
l’autre aux points $A',B',C'$; si
l’on a
\vspace{.58em}
\[\frac{AB}{A'B"}=\frac{AC}{A'C'},\]
les trois droites $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$
concourent en un même point.
&
69$'$. Théorème corrélatif:

\vspace{1em}
Deux points parallèles (n° 54)
sont joints à trois points 
$aa'$, $bb'$, $cc'$,
l’un par les droites $a,b,c$,
l’autre par les droites $a',b' c'$;
si l’on a (n°~53)
\[\biggl(\frac{ab}{a'b'}\biggr)=\biggl(\frac{ac}{a'c'}\biggr),\]
les points $aa'$, $bb'$, $cc'$ sont en ligne droite.

\end{longtable}

Nous placerons ici une remarque : les définitions que
nous avons posées sont fort utiles pour opérer ces déductions
corrélatives de théorèmes connus, mais leà énoncés
qui en résultent peuvent être modifiés en remontant au
sens contenu dans ces définitions. Ainsi le théorème
précédent deviendra :
\end{document}
```

Gives me:

[image]

Comment: `{p{.65\textwidth}|p{.65\textwidth}}` er that can't fit! your table is `1.3\textwidth+4\tabcolsep  + \arrayrulewidth` wide, and that's bigger than \textwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It isn't clear what you want to do, so a couple of alternatives:

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[textwidth=9.5cm, textheight=20cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

Nous n’insisterons pas davantage sur ce sujet et nous
allons passer maintenant aux applications (1).

\vspace{1em}
\centerline{X. — \textsc{Applications}.}

\vspace{1em}
\centerline{\textit{Transformations des propriétés segmentair es.}}

\vspace{1em}

\section*{Original}

\begin{longtable}[c]{p{.65\textwidth}|p{.65\textwidth}}
69. Prenons d’abord ce théorème:

\vspace{1em}
Deux droites parallèles sont
coupées par trois droites $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$,
l’une aux points $A,B,C$,
l’autre aux points $A',B',C'$; si
l’on a
\vspace{.58em}
\[\frac{AB}{A'B"}=\frac{AC}{A'C'},\]
les trois droites $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$
concourent en un même point.
&
69$'$. Théorème corrélatif:

\vspace{1em}
Deux points parallèles (n° 54)
sont joints à trois points 
$aa'$, $bb'$, $cc'$,
l’un par les droites $a,b,c$,
l’autre par les droites $a',b' c'$;
si l’on a (n°~53)
\[\biggl(\frac{ab}{a'b'}\biggr)=\biggl(\frac{ac}{a'c'}\biggr),\]
les points $aa'$, $bb'$, $cc'$ sont en ligne droite.

\end{longtable}

Nous placerons ici une remarque : les définitions que
nous avons posées sont fort utiles pour opérer ces déductions
corrélatives de théorèmes connus, mais leà énoncés
qui en résultent peuvent être modifiés en remontant au
sens contenu dans ces définitions. Ainsi le théorème
précédent deviendra :

\clearpage

\section*{Fit to text width}
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{.5\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                     p{.5\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}@{}}
69. Prenons d’abord ce théorème:

\vspace{1em}
Deux droites parallèles sont
coupées par trois droites $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$,
l’une aux points $A,B,C$,
l’autre aux points $A',B',C'$; si
l’on a
\vspace{.58em}
\[\frac{AB}{A'B"}=\frac{AC}{A'C'},\]
les trois droites $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$
concourent en un même point.
&
69$'$. Théorème corrélatif:

\vspace{1em}
Deux points parallèles (n° 54)
sont joints à trois points 
$aa'$, $bb'$, $cc'$,
l’un par les droites $a,b,c$,
l’autre par les droites $a',b' c'$;
si l’on a (n°~53)
\[\biggl(\frac{ab}{a'b'}\biggr)=\biggl(\frac{ac}{a'c'}\biggr),\]
les points $aa'$, $bb'$, $cc'$ sont en ligne droite.

\end{longtable}

Nous placerons ici une remarque : les définitions que
nous avons posées sont fort utiles pour opérer ces déductions
corrélatives de théorèmes connus, mais leà énoncés
qui en résultent peuvent être modifiés en remontant au
sens contenu dans ces définitions. Ainsi le théorème
précédent deviendra :

\clearpage

\section*{Overhang both margins}
{\LTleft=0pt minus 1fill \LTright=\LTleft
\begin{longtable}{p{.65\textwidth}|p{.65\textwidth}}
69. Prenons d’abord ce théorème:

\vspace{1em}
Deux droites parallèles sont
coupées par trois droites $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$,
l’une aux points $A,B,C$,
l’autre aux points $A',B',C'$; si
l’on a
\vspace{.58em}
\[\frac{AB}{A'B"}=\frac{AC}{A'C'},\]
les trois droites $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$
concourent en un même point.
&
69$'$. Théorème corrélatif:

\vspace{1em}
Deux points parallèles (n° 54)
sont joints à trois points 
$aa'$, $bb'$, $cc'$,
l’un par les droites $a,b,c$,
l’autre par les droites $a',b' c'$;
si l’on a (n°~53)
\[\biggl(\frac{ab}{a'b'}\biggr)=\biggl(\frac{ac}{a'c'}\biggr),\]
les points $aa'$, $bb'$, $cc'$ sont en ligne droite.

\end{longtable}
}

Nous placerons ici une remarque : les définitions que
nous avons posées sont fort utiles pour opérer ces déductions
corrélatives de théorèmes connus, mais leà énoncés
qui en résultent peuvent être modifiés en remontant au
sens contenu dans ces définitions. Ainsi le théorème
précédent deviendra :
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes `Overhang both margins` is what I was after. Will you expand upon `{\LTleft=0pt minus 1fill \LTright=\LTleft
\begin{longtable}{p{.65\textwidth}|p{.65\textwidth}}`. Is `=0pt minus 1` doing math? For example is equivalent to `=-1`? And I understand `\fill` in other contexts, but don't understand plain fill here.

Comment: @JeffHiggins 0pt minus 1fill is a length with natural length 0pt but may shrink to arbitrary negative size the `1`  is part of `1fill`, the shrink component

Comment: Ok, now opening my `\TeX book` to chapter 12. Much appreciated.